# How to transfer and execute .exe(py2exe) file in remote windows machines in a network using python

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I have a set of python files which takes the information from windows registry,I have converted these files in to a .exe using py2exe.Now I need to scan the network and detect the active endpoints in it, after detecting the endpoint/machines in the network I need to send this .exe to to the machines and make it execute.How to do this in python.I have a code for transfer of files,My problem is how to execute the .exe file in remote windows machine (I have the credentials of the machine)& get back the results to the server?

I need to accomplish this task using python.

Any help or suggestions please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the OS of the machines? Are you using `ftp` for the file transfer? I wonder if you could use `rcmd` for this purpose?

Comment: Hi, Floris Im using followinfg code to transfer files http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/